# Countable or uncountable number of functions with the given property.

Tags: functions, summation

This question was asked in TIFR GS2015 Maths Paper.
Let f be a function from {1,2,...,10} to R such that
$$ \left (\sum_{i=1}^{10}\dfrac{|f(i)|}{2^i} \right )^2 = \left (\sum_{i=1}^{10}|f(i)|^2 \right ) \left ( \sum_{i=1}^{10}\dfrac{1}{4^i}\right )$$ Then how many such f are there and are they countable or uncountable?
I tried solving it but just couldn't move forward. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this page - particularly the part the covers when equality holds: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HoeldersInequalities.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Apply the [Cauchy-Schwartz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality); when is it an equality?

Answer (score 1):

By [Cauchy Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), equality holds when $(f(1),...,f(10))$ is a multiple of $(2^{-1},..,2^{-10})$.